# Numba: Fast way of replacing keys with values in an array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, numba

I want to replace `keys` with `values` in an large size `array` having repeating elements. I am trying `numba` and `numpy` mapping method. The code for both approaches are as follows.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

array1 = np.arange(150*150*150, dtype=int)
array2 = np.arange(150*150*150, dtype=int)
array = np.concatenate((array1, array2))

keys = np.arange(50)
values = -1 * np.arange(50)

## Numba Approach
@njit(parallel=True)
def numba_replace(array, keys, values):

    for i in prange(len(keys)):
        for j in prange(len(array)):
            if array[j] == keys[i]:
               array[j] = values[i]


## numpy approach
def numpy_replace(array, keys, values):

    mapp = np.arange(array.size)
    mapp[keys] = values
    mapped = mapp[array]

    return mapped

## Performance 
%%timeit
numba_replace(array, keys, values)
# 117 ms ± 969 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
numpy_replace(array, keys, values)
# 61.2 ms ± 159 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Although `numpy_replace` is 2x faster than `numba_replace` but I don't prefer to use it as my array size is very big `(3000 x 3000 x 3000)`and numpy method creates a `new array` increasing memory usage. Is there any way to make numba_replace faster or any method that doesn't create new array during process?

Comment: How large is keys,values  in your real world example? And what is the percentage of values to replace?

Comment: len(keys) is approximately 1000000. len(values) = len(keys)

Comment: Percentage varies as per situation but I would say it in between 0.1 to 5% approximately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Improving the Numba method (reducing complexity)**

Since you only want to change a relatively small amount of values, you can use a set to determine if the actual array element has to be changed. 
Additionally you can use search_sorted to get the right key, value pair. For this small example the difference isn't that big, but the difference will get a lot bigger if the problem size increases.

**Implementation**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

@njit(parallel=True)
def numba_replace(array, keys, values):
    ind_sort=np.argsort(keys)
    keys_sorted=keys[ind_sort]
    values_sorted=values[ind_sort]
    s_keys=set(keys)

    for j in prange(array.shape[0]):
        if array[j] in s_keys:
            ind = np.searchsorted(keys_sorted,array[j])
            array[j]=values_sorted[ind]
    return array
```

**Timings**

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange

array1 = np.arange(150*150*150, dtype=int)
array2 = np.arange(150*150*150, dtype=int)
array = np.concatenate((array1, array2))

#to get proper timings do nothing here
#changing the array in-place will obviously have 
#an influence on the timings, because there are no values to change in the second run
keys = np.arange(50)
values = np.arange(50)

%timeit numba_replace(array, keys, values)
# 20.1 ms ± 1.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%timeit numpy_replace(array, keys, values)
# 51.3 ms ± 392 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: The code seems to work fine for the arrays I am dealing with. Thanks a lot @max9111. One point I wanted to ask is that in case `len(keys)` is very large, making a `set(keys)` becomes a slow process. How will you overcome this situation?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that:

```
array[keys] = values
```

does the job in numpy, without creating any new array

**EDIT:** Just to check that the command performs the same operation as your `numpy_replace` function:

```
mapped = numpy_replace(array, keys, values)
array[keys] = values
print(all(mapped == array)) # --> True
```

Comment: this is the standard way if elements in array are not repeating. But incase the elements are repeating then we need to map as I did in numpy_replace method. Currently I have created array of non repeating integers as a sample array but in my actual case elements in the array are repeating.

Comment: @ZAK : well, that information SHOULD have been in the OP, don't you think so? Providing sample data that does not illustrate your real problem is rarely a good idea...

Comment: I have edited the question and tried to make it more user friendly. I hope this helps. @sciroccorics

Comment: @ZAK : Excellent editing! Things are much clearer now. Unfortunately, for such a case, I have no idea how to avoid the additional indirection array when using numpy.